# if else in .append based value of field in json to selected a select option html

Tags: php, jquery, json

```
$(document).on('click', '.bg-maroon', function () {

        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url('surveyor/c_surveyor_inspection/get_data_untuk_inspection_surveyor_dua'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ID: id
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
```

I get json like this :

```
{
"header": [{
    "NO_INSPECTION": "55",
    "ID_CONDITION": "3",
    "NAMA_CONDITION": "CLEAN"
}],
"transaction": [{
    "NO_INSPECTION": "55",
    "ID_ITEM_INSPECTION": "1",
    "NOMOR_ITEM_INSPECTION": "1",
    "NAMA_ITEM_INSPECTION": "Protection Box Cover",
    "CONDITION": "9",
    "ALIAS": "BE",
    "NAME_ITEM": "BENT"
}, {
    "NO_INSPECTION": "55",
    "ID_ITEM_INSPECTION": "2",
    "NOMOR_ITEM_INSPECTION": "2a",
    "NAMA_ITEM_INSPECTION": "Manhole LID, Fastening Bolts",
    "CONDITION": "7",
    "ALIAS": "B",
    "NAME_ITEM": "BROKEN"
}]
}
```

Please, see on `transaction` array json. There is two object that will be representated into two row html table. I colaborated php with jquery. 
My problem is, I want to make option will be selected based `"ID_ITEM_INSPECTION"` field above. This is the jquery combine php that I will be added in success ajax:

```
$.each(response.transaction, function(i, item){
    console.log(response.transaction[i].ID_ITEM_INSPECTION);
      $('#list2').find('tbody').append('<tr class="list2_var">' +
         '<td>' +
             '<select class="form-control" name="list2_item_0" id="list2_name_0">' +
                 '<option disabled selected>Pilih jenis kerusakan... </option>' +
                 '<?php
                     foreach ($top_item->result() as $v) {
                       echo '<option value =' . $v->ID_ITEM_INSPECTION . ' >' . $v->NOMOR_ITEM_INSPECTION . '    - ' . $v->NAMA_ITEM_INSPECTION . '</option>';
                   }
                  ?>' +
           '</select>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="del_area04">' +
          '<button type="button" class="list2_del btn btn-block btn-danger" style="display: block;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>' +
        '</td>' +
    '<tr>');
  });
```

So, the condition is, if in select option is same on `response.transaction[i].ID_ITEM_INSPECTION`, that option in select will be selected. Is it possible ? 
Any help it so appreciated

Comment: Do you have access to `ID_ITEM_INSPECTION` (from JSON) in php?

Comment: json_decode do you mean ?

Comment: No, i mean if you have variable in php, you can do something like this:
`echo '<option value="..."' + YOUR_VAR ==  $v->ID_ITEM_INSPECTION ? 'selected="selected"' : '""'>`

Comment: I am sorry Iam not, coz the json based callback ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after your `append` function:

```
$('.form-control option[value="' + response.transaction[i].ID_ITEM_INSPECTION + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Look at this example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjeaqx9L/